# How to use impersonate_service_account for streaming beam pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, impersonation

how can I run beam pipeline locally (`DirectRunner`) in `streaming` mode using **impersonate_service_account** credentials? (in python3)

I want to get rid of Service Account key file (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable)

here's minimal code

```
options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).impersonate_service_account = <MY SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL>
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
source = pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB,
                               with_attributes=True,
                               timestamp_attribute = "evt_time")
```

where can I set source credentials (my own GCP user account credentials set via `gcloud auth application-default login`)
i checked source code for PipelineOptions(), ReadFromPubSub() - none seem to have suitable way to inject source credentials.

thank you for advice.

Thank you for your advice ?

Comment: Will you also impersonate the service account with DataflowRunner?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i believe not.. basically I want to test run the pipeline running locally on localhost first (using DirectRunner) - but in order to run, I need to listen to Pub/Sub streams  (source) and stream t BigQuery (Sink)... in the past I had been using Service Account key file and that worked fine.. but o want to get rid of Key File (as it is un-secure)

Comment: Can you try to remove the service account impersonation in your code (because locally and in the cloud, the code should be exactly the same to be sure it works fine), and perform that command `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<SA email>`. This command should create an impersonated credential on your computer. however, my latest tests (about 1 year ago) show me that a few libraries/languages were compliant... Anyway, have a try!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thx for the suggestion.. I tried. this is the error the pipeline code gives --- `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: The file /Users/mac/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json does not have a valid type. Type is impersonated_service_account, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account', 'external_account').`

Comment: That's what I said, Python library is not up to date to support that credential type. It is supported in Java and in Go (because I implemented it in Go).

Comment: Thank for clarification - so basically there is no way to run streaming pipeline locally without a) generating Service Account key file,  or b) giving User a direct access to Cloud resource  .. both of which are not security best practice in general ..

Comment: Stating **both of which are not security best practice in general** is not correct. Security rules require context and appropriate application. In your example, the user requires credentials. That does not violate a security best practice.

Comment: @JohnHanley there will always be some "weak links". what I meant is, it is generally NOT RECOMMENDED <a> to generate and download a service account key to use a service account <B> to not give User direct access to Cloud resources, instead grant Service Accounts access to Cloud resources and have User impersonate them when running / testing locally. and that's what I try to do when developing beam pipeline locally! before actually deploying on DataFlow.

Comment: If a user requires credentials, granting them credentials is just fine. There are several factors to manage: 1) security the environment where credentials are stored. 2) Managing the credentials. 3) You cannot impersonate credentials without credentials as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: they're stored locally in `application_default_credentials.json` file (set after running $gcloud auth application-default login). as i mentioned in my previous comments

Comment: I am not sure how your last comment contributes to my answer and comments. Of course, I know where credentials are stored. I know their format, their history, what they are used for, and why.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to avoid exporting a key file, you can use a `User` [principal](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/principal-identifiers#v1) and configure your gcloud SDK with [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

> This command is useful when you are developing code that would normally use a service account but need to run the code in a local development environment where it's easier to provide user credentials. The credentials will apply to all API calls that make use of the Application Default Credentials client library. Do not set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable if you want to use the credentials generated by this command in your local development.

Or if you are trying to create an impersonating chain, you can use comma separated SAs in the impersonate_service_account pipeline option `{delegated_principal},{targeted_principal}`. The auth logic that extracts the information is [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b77413309ef3032a6422428cc430eca67582ff61/sdks/python/apache_beam/internal/gcp/auth.py#L172)

Comment: @nnigk yes, this is exactly what i try to achieve! but still getting error... in-fact, The auth logic code you refer, that whole module doesn't get called at all - I run my pipeline code locally (DirectRunner). -heres my minimal code https://github.com/vibhorj/so/blob/master/df/so-73348611/scrap.py

Comment: this is the error I keep getting `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 User not authorized to perform this action.`
I already executed  `gcloud auth application-default login`, and my User alreday has Token Creator role on the Service Account

Comment: To let a user impersonate a service account, you could grant the user the Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the service account.

Comment: User already had Service Account Token Creator role. Just upgraded to Service Account User, but the result is the same. (already waited 10min. for updated permissions to trickle across the system...)

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled, why the the method `_get_service_credentials()` not getting called at all! (based on my debugging).. this could be the root of the issues...

Comment: I can confirm Beam is installed with the gcp extra - `$ pip install "apache-beam[gcp]"`

Comment: a gentle bump, if you got time .. any clue would be highly useful!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not all Google Cloud services support ADC `impersonated_service_account`.

If you are not running on a Google Cloud compute service, you will need credentials on the system. Using the CLI gcloud just masks the fact that credentials are still stored on the system. The CLI is for developer convenience and not for security. You are trying to switch from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to another method that requires storing different credentials. **That will not improve your security**.

Even if you used OAuth User credentials and then switched to impersonated credentials (I have written articles on that), you still store credentials and secrets on the local system. Basically, you have a chicken and egg situation. **You need credentials to impersonate other credentials**. When running in the cloud, those credentials are managed for you. Outside the cloud, you manage the credentials.